# Swift 2 Recover a value of class

Tags: ios, swift, class, swift2

I extracted my data from my api and initialized these data on my class.

```
class User {
init(login: NSString, email: NSString, last_name: NSString, first_name: NSString) {
    self.login = login
    self.email = email
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.first_name = first_name
}
var login: NSString = ""
var email: NSString = ""
var last_name: NSString = ""
var first_name: NSString = "" }

func extract_data_user(Data: NSDictionary) {
let login: NSString = Data.valueForKey("login") as! NSString
let internal_email: NSString = Data.valueForKey("internal_email") as! NSString
let lastname: NSString = Data.valueForKey("lastname") as! NSString
let firstname: NSString = Data.valueForKey("firstname") as! NSString
_ = User(login: login, email: internal_email, last_name: lastname,
    first_name: first name) }
```

I would like to create a function for display this data , but when i create variable for example 'var user = User()' Xcode ask me to insert all the arguments .

I want recover for exemple the string of 'login' without initializing yet.

Answer (score 0):

`Xcode` is asking you to insert all arguments because you have only one initializer of `User` class which takes all the arguments. If you want to do something like this:

```
let user = User()
```

You must add another initializer to your `User` class:

```
class User {
    init() {
        // code...
    }

    // remaining code of User class...
}
```

**Edit**

And also your code looks really bad. For me, it should look like:

```
class User {
    var login: String?
    var email: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var firstName: String?

    init(login: String, email: String, lastName: String, firstName: String) {
        self.login = login
        self.email = email
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.firstName = firstName
    }

    convenience init(data: NSDictionary) {
        let login = data.valueForKey("login") as! String
        let email = data.valueForKey("internal_email") as! String
        let lastName = data.valueForKey("lastname") as! String
        let firstName = data.valueForKey("firstname") as! String
        self.init(login: login, email: email, lastName: lastName, firstName: firstName)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(login: "", email: "", lastName: "", firstName: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't undestand what I 'm suppose to do .   What do you mean by initializing another ?

Comment: You need to add another initializer to your `User` class, like in my answer.

Comment: I've just edited my post, so you can look and see how I see your `User` class

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value of a property of a class without initializing it first.

You should create an

```
init(data:NSDictionary){
  let login: NSString = data.valueForKey("login") as! NSString
  let internal_email: NSString = data.valueForKey("internal_email") as! NSString
  let lastname: NSString = data.valueForKey("lastname") as! NSString
  let firstname: NSString = data.valueForKey("firstname") as! NSString
  _ = User(login: login, email: internal_email, last_name: lastname,
    first_name: first name)}
```

then say:

```
let user = User(data)
```

Now you can say

```
print(user.login)
```